Why is recovery mode not read-only?
I have just run rm and removed a file I am now attempting to recover - alas, I have not implemented a git version system. So, I am booting into recovery mode. The problem I have is I can write to the disk, which is concerning.
The steps I take are:

reboot the system
From GRUB, select boot into recovery mode
A GUI selection screen is then shown, stating the system is read-only.
I select the option to drop into the root shell
I am now in a bash shell. I then run touch test. A file named 'test' is created.

My problem is in step (5): if this is a read-only file system, I shouldn't be able to create a new file. So, I have powered off my computer and am investigating, to ensure I don't overwrite the blocks containing my deleted file.
Why is my system not in read-only mode ?
Other info:

the file I am attempting to recover was in the root file system
One approach I may take is to use extundelete, if this is not installed on my system currently, can I install it while the root fs is in read only mode ?
if I cannot install extundelete, does anyone have recommendations of packages that are likely pre-installed on an Ubuntu OS ?

Any suggestions or thoughts on the steps (1), (2) or (3) above are also greatly appreciated.

There are several possible meanings of of "recovery".  In Recovery Mode, "recovery" means "repair a broken system", which requires write access. Not "data recovery", which could indeed be read-only.


Why is recovery mode not read-only?

Recovery mode means: root. No limit on permissions or passwords asked.

One approach I may take is to use extundelete, if this is not installed on my system currently, can I install it while the root fs is in read only mode ?

No. The number 1 rule: do not write to the disk.
You start up a live session (the one you use to install Ubuntu) and install extundelete from there (so it is installed in memory not on disk) and from there you try to find the file to restore it.
In case you need to restore a lot of files or a complete partition it is better to get a larger USB stick and then diskdump (dd) the whole partition onto the USB and then restore it on the USB.
-any- write can be fatal in restoring that section it wrote onto the disk. Restoring 1 layer is possible. Restoring from a write after another write... unlikely

Thankyou for your response - my system is set up as a dual boot. The other OS is windows. I expect there to be a means of booting into my Windows OS, and recovering files on the Ubuntu partition from there. Have you attempted something similar before ?

No. I never use windows ;)  If you know the name of the file and it is indeed a file in "/" (aka root) and not a personal fileyou can also retrieve it from the repositories or from a tarbal you download. Seems the easier method to me.
